# CONTAO .cto file giving error

Tags: themes, contao

I'm trying to import theme using .cto file. That theme is working perfectly fine in one contao installation (4.4.14). But when i tried to import that .cto (exported file) in other 4.4.14 contao installation then it's giving error. **Theme "theme-file-name.cto" is corrupt and cannot be imported."** I'm not getting what should be a problem.

See screenshot for more detail

[image]

Comment: Try updating both installations to Contao 4.4.21 first, before exporting and importing the theme.

Comment: No luck. Even i export one of theme and if i import in same contao project then also giving same error. No idea what should be an issue.

Comment: May be there's a bug. Please post your reproduction with Contao `4.4.21` where you export the theme and then re-import the theme in the _same_ Contao installation again here on Github: https://github.com/contao/contao/issues